# Password validator with property file design

Tags: spring, validation, jsf, jakarta-ee

i have a validator component:

```
@Component("passwordValidator")
@Scope("view")
public class PasswordValidator implements Validator {

    private int maxPasswordLength;

}
```

and i want to set the value for the property `maxPasswordLength` from a property file
i am confused between setting it in build time with dependency injection or during each validation in the validate method or in @PostConstrcut method ?

what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2.0 and 2.1 do not respect @PostConstruct, @Resource, @Inject, etc in validators. JSF 2.2 should bring support for this.